# Editing bucketed items with multiple versions in the content editor

Tags: content-editor, buckets

The issue is located in the content editor (using Sitecore 8.1-upd1 btw):

1. we search for an item inside a bucket and go to it (it opens in a new tab in the requested version - here v3) - lets call this 'item1'
2. we navigate to any other item outside the bucket
3. we go back to our bucket
4. we click on the tab (which is still there) with our first 'item1'
5. this 'item1' is now shown in version 1, even if it does not exist anymore

Does anybody know a fix for this? Is it still the case in later versions?

And: is there maybe another way of viewing/editing bucketed items that we can use to work around this issue?

**Update**: as this is a known bug now - is there another way to edit the items and keep the search interface for the editors?

Comment: I can reproduce this on 8.1 update 3. It is a bug and I don't think there is any solution for it beside getting a patch.

Comment: I assume there is indeed no real solution - but is there a workaround? Another way of viewing items within buckets that does not involve the tabs maybe?

Comment: I would make sure that if there is consensus that this might be an undocumented sitecore bug, someone that can clearly describe the issue should log a Sitecore Support ticket on it.

Comment: Ticket is made, and bug is reported...

Comment: But still looking for the workaround.. I though there was another way of opening items from the bucket search (configurable). Let's see if the community can get the answer before Sitecore support does ;)

Comment: Can you come up with a better title for this one @Gatogordo? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alhough the information from Chris was very useful - and the issue is a registered bug now - I do want to share the workaround that we found.

In the Sitecore content editor, as an admin locate the `/settings/Buckets/Item Bucket Settings` item. The first field is "`Show Results in`". Here you can choose how you want items from a bucket search to be displayed in the content editor. The default option is a new tab:

- New tab (default)
- New editor window : will open the item in a new window within the content editor environment
- New tab not selected: same as new tab but without setting the selection to it

[image]

Note that this setting is for all buckets in your instance. Our workaround was to change this to "New Content Editor". The user experience for editing these items in the content editor was slightly changed this way, but the bug was no more.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

You might be able to workaround the issue using only the search interface if you explicitly configure the 'version' search filter:

[image: Configure Search Filters]

Steps:

1. Click on the arrow drop-down (left of the search box) to bring up the search fly-out
2. Click on the 'Search Filters' link, and then select 'Search by version'
3. In the search box, the 'Version' filter should now be visible.  Fill in the appropriate version number (2), and then click on the icon to the left of the 'Version' text until it changes to the 'plus' symbol.
4. Finally, fill in the rest of your search query as you had it before.

This should filter down the search results to the appropriate item, with the appropriate version.

**Original workaround:**

@maziar-rezaei is correct - I believe this is a bug in Sitecore.

As a workaround, you can go to the 'View' tab in the Sitecore ribbon in Content Editor, and then select the 'Buckets' checkbox:

[image: Select Buckets in View tab]

This will allow you to view the underlying tree structure of the Sitecore bucket, allowing you to directly find and then edit the item in question.

Comment: Could be a solution, but this way I loose some effects of the bucket.. the editors will not know where to find the items in the tree, they need the simple search functionality

Comment: If you haven't, I recommend opening a Sitecore Support ticket. There's probably a hotfix for this out there.